# Polynomial Remainder

Tags: polynomials

[image: Question]

I have totally no idea how to solve this question. Any help is appreciated.

Maybe one could try to Rewrite the remainder as R(x)=(something)/(P(x))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $P(x)-P(a)$ is divisible by $x-a$.

Write

$$P(x)-P(a)=(x-a)Q(x)$$

Also $Q(x)-Q(b)$ is divisible by $x-b$. Thus

$$Q(x)-Q(b)=(x-b)S(x)$$

From the first relation we get $P(b)-P(a)=(b-a)Q(b)$, thus

$$Q(x)=\frac{P(b)-P(a)}{b-a}+(x-b)S(x) \,.$$

Plugging this in the first relation we get:

$$P(x)=P(a)+(x-a)Q(x)=P(a)+\frac{P(b)-P(a)}{b-a}(x-a)+(x-a)(x-b)S(x) \,.$$

From here the conclusion follows immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is the remainder, you have
$$\tag1P(x)=Q(x)\cdot (x-a)(x-b)+R(x)$$
Show that $\deg R\le 1$, hence $R$ can be written as $R(x)=u(x-a)+v$. What does $(1)$ tell you if you lpug in $x=a$ and $x=b$?